# Norm of the operator that zeroes out parts of a sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm studying Kreyszig's "Introductory Functional Analysis" and couldn't understand one of the examples. There is a sequence of operators $\{T_n\}$ where the operator $T_n:\ell^2\to \ell^2$ is defined by
$$
T_nx = (\underbrace{0,0,...,0}_n,a_{n+1},a_{n+2},a_{n+3}...)
$$
here $x=(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}...)\in\ell^2$. Why exactly does the norm of the operator equal to $\|T_n\|=1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly $\|T_nx\|_2\le\|x\|_2$ for every $x\in\ell_2$. Thus $\|T_n\|\le 1$. To prove $\|T_n\|=1$, it suffices to find some norm one vector $x$ in $\ell_2$ such that $\|T_nx\|=1$. Well consider $x=(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$, where $a_{n+1}=1$ and $a_j=0$ for $j\ne n+1$. Then $x$ and
$$
T(x)=(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)
$$
each have norm one.

Answer (score 2):

The operator $T_n$ is an orthogonal projection. It is a projection because applying the same operator twice yields the same answer. It is orthogonal because $T_nx$ is orthogonal to $(I-T_n)y$ for all $x,y$. Consequently,
$$
                 \|x\|^2 = \|(I-T_n)x+T_nx\|^2=\|(I-T_n)x\|^2+\|T_nx\|^2.
$$
Therefore, $\|(I-T_n)x\| \le \|x\|$ and $\|T_nx\| \le \|x\|$ for all $x$. So both $T_n$ and $I-T_n$ have norms bounded by $1$. The norm of $T_n$ is $1$ because, if $T_nx \ne 0$, then
$$
       \|T_n(T_nx)\|=\|T_nx\| \\
         \implies \|T_n y \|=\|y\|,\;\;\; y =T_nx.
$$